# jquery datepicker not working clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am working on jquery datepicker.It is working on clicking on a button but only in mozilla firefox but not in google chrome not in IE too.Please tell me what to do so that the datepicker will work in all browsers.Please the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/hM7q3/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="selectdate" value=""> 


<textarea name="dates" id="dates" maxlength="160" placeholder="your message" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( "#selectdate" ).datepicker({ 
altField: $('#dates').val(), 
numberOfMonths:1, 
altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
minDate: -0, 
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) { 
$("#selectdate").val(''); 

$('#dates').val($('#dates').val()+','+selectedDate); 
} 
});
```

Comment: have you tried it in different version of IE and goolge chrome?

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me in chrome(Version 30.0.1599.101)...

Comment: @Nikhil I am using oracle linux and the google version that i use shows uptodate.

Comment: @Nikhil Is it possible to throw an alert if client is some version that jaquery datepicker does not support

Comment: @PragneshChauhan Yes its working in higher version in google chrome.I am using oracle linux and 26 is the latest version.So it was not working.Well it it possible to throw an alert to client if some part of jquery like datepicker will not work if uses lower versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following..

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmpS/8/)

JS:

```
$("#selectdate").datepicker({
    altField: $('#dates').val(),
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: -0,
    buttonImage: 'http://placehold.it/32',
    showOn: "both",
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#selectdate").val('');

        var attr = $("#dates").attr("selectedDate");
        if (typeof (attr) !== 'undefined' && attr !== '') {
            if ($('#dates').val() !== '') {
                var tmpVal = $('#dates').val().substring(0,$('#dates').val().indexOf(attr));
               console.log(tmpVal); 
              $('#dates').val(tmpVal + selectedDate);
              $('#dates').attr("selectedDate", selectedDate);
            } else {
                $('#dates').val(selectedDate);
            }
        } else {
            $('#dates').attr("selectedDate", selectedDate);
            $('#dates').val($('#dates').val() + selectedDate);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Isnt in this http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/ possible like the way you did?

Answer (score 1):

Not able to recreate the problem... but I think what you need is to use the [showOn](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn) and [buttonImage](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage) options instead of using a button to render the datepicker

like

```
<input type="text" id="selectdate" value="" style="display: none">
```

then

```
$("#selectdate").datepicker({
    altField: $('#dates').val(),
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: -0,
    buttonImage:'http://placehold.it/32',
    showOn: "both",
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#selectdate").val('');

        $('#dates').val($('#dates').val() + ',' + selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zqmpS/)

Comment: thanks its working in my old version but the code you have provided accepts multiple dates if button is clicked multiple times.Isnt it possible to remove the older date and replaced it new date

Comment: @javaBeginner what do you mean by multiple dates

Comment: see when I press the button 2 times I get dates **,10/30/2013,10/29/2013** but I want if I press the button 2nd time then old date will be replaced with the new date so **,10/30/2013,** will become **,10/29/2013**

Comment: @javaBeginner Replace  $('#dates').val($('#dates').val() + ',' + selectedDate); with  $('#dates').val(selectedDate);

Comment: @Nikhil see Suppose I enter **hello** then pressed the button then it replaces the **hello** But I want **hello 10/28/2013**

Comment: You just want to preserve the inputted value(apart from date) right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39965/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-nikhil)

Comment: @ArunPJohny in http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/ isnt it possible to append text with datepicker

Comment: @ArunPJohny Isnt in this http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/ possible like the way you did?