# Datetimepicker Markup Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

If I want to add a new date, I have no problem, but if I pull the date from SQL and display it in value, the problem is that the button does not open. I searched on the internet, but I could not find an example.

```
<div class='col-sm-2'>
    <div class='form-group mt-30 mb-30'>
        <label clas='control-label mb-10 text-left'>Kalkış Tarihi & Saati</label>
        <div class='input-group date'>
            <input id='deneme' name='eski_gelis_kalkis_saati' type='text' class='form-control' value='03.02.2019 13:10'>
            <div class='input-group-addon'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th'></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code is below

```
$('#deneme').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'tr',
}).data("DateTimePicker").date(moment());
```

How can I display value with change date?

My local date format is for example 03.02.2018 10:10 dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format date in jQuery datetimepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802190/how-do-i-format-date-in-jquery-datetimepicker)

Comment: button doesn't work, because the format date you are passing to datetimepicker is in incorrect format. so datetimepicker not accept it, and give you error in developer console of your browser.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19580797/5813861) also

Comment: Hello @yash thanks for answer and helping.